# call list fragment from the same list fragment and backpress button

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, fragment

A --> list fragment

B -->list fragment (calling from A)

C -->same of B(calling from B)

I am using these functions to call B from A ;

```
>   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
>               if (fm != null) {
>                   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
>                   ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, entryListFragment);
>           ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
>                   ft.addToBackStack(null);
>                   ft.commit();
```

And this is my  FragmentActivity class;

```
public class FragmentTabActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_tab);

        Commons.globalContext = this;    
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        TabFragment tabFragment = (TabFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_tab);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Log.e("BACK STACK", "" + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());

        if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }           
}
```

When i back press from B ,I can go back A,but I can't go back from C to B.
Thanks for help

EDIT:I solved this way:

public class FragmentTabActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private Global globalClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    globalClass = ((Global) getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_tab);

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new MainOnBackStackChangedListener());

}



private class MainOnBackStackChangedListener implements
        OnBackStackChangedListener {

    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        Log.e("Stack COUNT", "" + 
    getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    try {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {


                int lastIndex=globalClass.historyList.size()-1;

                globalClass.historyList.remove(lastIndex);

                for (int i = 0; i <globalClass.counterForBackPress; i++) {

                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }   

        } else {
                     FragmentTabActivity.this.finish();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i am facing same problem too...